# VPN client blocked through squid server

Tags: vpn, proxy, squid

I have a computer running debian between the local network and the load balancer who connects to the internet. Everything is fine, that computer has a Squid running inside, BUT we have a problem with VPNs, everyone inside the office can't reach the VPN server, when we remove that computer between the load balancer and the local network everything is fine.

Our debian machine is running squid in transparent mode with bridged configuration to bypass all the data from the load balancer who acts a router too.

I think I need some iptables rule to forward the VPN data

```
root@squid:~# iptables -vnL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 225K packets, 182M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spts:67:68 dpts:67:68 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp spts:67:68 dpts:67:68
```

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 193K packets, 77M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 240K packets, 185M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

```
root@squid:~# iptables -vnL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 7172 packets, 1019K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

 2585  151K REDIRECT   tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 redir ports 3128 
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 redir ports 3128 
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth1   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 redir ports 3128 
    0     0 REDIRECT   tcp  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 redir ports 3128
```

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 8621 packets, 1092K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1625 packets, 97780 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

```
root@squid:~# cat /etc/squid/squid.conf
cache_effective_user squid
cache_effective_user squid
http_port 3128 transparent
```

cache_dir ufs /home/bridge/squid/cache 2000 16 256

cache_access_log /var/log/squid/access.log
cache_log /var/log/squid/cache.log
cache_store_log none

emulate_httpd_log on

cache_mem 16 MB

hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
acl QUERY urlpath_regex cgi-bin \? asp aspx jsp
no_cache deny QUERY

hosts_file /etc/hosts

refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern . 0 40% 4320

acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0

### Define your network below

acl mynetwork src 192.168.0.0/24
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8
acl purge method PURGE
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 21 # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https

acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 #unregistered ports

acl SSL_ports port 443 563

http_access allow manager localhost
http_access allow manager
http_access allow purge localhost
http_access allow purge
http_access allow !Safe_ports
http_access allow CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost
http_access allow mynetwork
http_access allow all
http_reply_access allow all
icp_access allow mynetwork

icp_access deny all

visible_hostname bridge

coredump_dir /etc/squid

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem adding a simple iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```